# How to add a cell automatically to a sheet when I add another cell on another sheet?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, vba

I have some time series data, so I will add one new data point to one excel sheet for several sheets in an excel file, then I also need to add all these new data point to another sheet, so that I can update the correlation matrix. Is there a simple way to add all these new data point to the correlation matrix sheet?

Comment: What have you tried and what, exactly is the problem?

Comment: It really depends on how your data sheets are setup. But formulas and VBA are potential routes to solutions. This general answer is because you asked a general question. Be specific and there's a better chance of receiving specific suggestions.

Comment: Could you provide a sample here?

Comment: Agreed is it is hard to make a suggestion without more data.  A risky was would be to right click on a worksheet, click select all. While all are selected make the change.